# I work remotely and use a managed co-working space. The cost of such is tax-deductible for freelancers. What options do permanent contract peole have?

Tags: united-kingdom, remote-work, taxes

This is in the UK.

Essentially what the title says. I am employed on a permanent contract and pay for my own co-working space. As this is an income-related expense, and I know my freelancing friends can tax-deduct it, I was wondering if employed co-workers have any similar tools at their disposal. As far as I could find co-working does not fall under any Salary Sacrifice schemes. Are there any other?

Comment: The obvious answer is your employer pays for it. If that was important to you, you could/should have negotiated it into your contract.

Comment: Are you self-employed as a contractor?

Comment: In the US, it isn't likely to be deductable as a business expense unless you are working in that space, rather than on the employer's site, at the request of and for the convenience of your employer. I have no idea what the UK rules would be.

Answer (score 9):

If (as it sounds) you're an employee of the company rather than a contractor then your only option for getting reimbursed for this would be ask your employer if you can expense it.

Will they? Well, you don't know until you ask! A great deal will depend on how this particular arrangement came about - if your employer asked you to use a co-working space that's going to be a pretty strong position from which to argue that it's a necessary business expense that they should be paying for.

On the other hand if it's something you chose to do purely on your own then it's going to be tough - probably the best angle would be to try and make a case to them that they are benefiting from you being more productive then you would be otherwise.  If you've got a annual or salary review coming up then a clever option would be to float the cost of the co-working space to them as either a partial or complete alternative to a raise - this would in effect replicate salary-sacrifice and is tax efficient for both parties.

Answer (score 4):

See [this link](https://www.gov.uk/tax-relief-for-employees) from the Government.

Essentially, if the expenses are over £2,500 you will need to fill in a Self Assessment, otherwise you can claim online.

As others have said, it is obviously better if the employer pays, but, if not, you can at least get the income tax back.

Comment: This answer actually answers the question. And it sounds correct to me, but I don’t know UK law.

Comment: That's a good shout actually.. doing an SA and claiming the tax back would actually put the OP in a similar position to a contractor putting the expense through their own business and it might be non-trivial amounts of money.